# Is HttpContext.Current Ever Null in a Web Application?

Tags: asp.net

Is HttpContext.Current ever null in a web Application (assuming threads are not being used)? More specifically, would it ever be null in `void Application_OnError(object sender, EventArgs e)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668447/asp-net-c-applicationerror-in-global-asax-cannot-access-session-variables)

> Session is not initialized until the AcquireRequestState event, so any error occurring before this point will not have session variables available.

I think the same applies to HttpContext.Current as HttpContext.Current.Session

So yes, I think HttpContext.Current can sometimes be null in Application_OnError

Comment: @codeulike - Yeah after reading xOn's and yours it does make sense that it can be null. I don't think I thought it through completely. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

There were some interesting changes in IIS 7 with respect to this. In IIS6, you had a HttpContext in Application_Start. From IIS7 onwards this is no longer the case.

More Information:

http://blogs.msdn.com/webtopics/archive/2009/02/12/webbaseevent-raise-method-fails-in-application-start-event-with-a-nullreferenceexception-on-iis-7-0.aspx

-Oisin

Comment: @xOn - yeah I'd read about this, but was wondering more specifically about OnError, mind you if something craps out during application start then it would be null in OnError.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it can happen if, for example, you spin off a worker thread, the response ends, and the worker thread throws an exception.  Your Application_OnError will catch the exception, but the HttpContext.Current will be null.